# Python - No audio output despite program reading exit code 0

Tags: python, audio, playsound

I am trying to create a program that converts text to Morse code and has a playback sound option. Issue seems to be that the program finishes correctly, reading exit code 0 but no sound is played. I have looked into other posts on this but they all seem to be for Windows, I am running Mac OS. Code is as follows, (sorry if it's a bit to long)

```
import pyaudio
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

MORSE_CODE_DICT = { 'A':'.-', 'B':'-...',
                    'C':'-.-.', 'D':'-..', 'E':'.',
                    'F':'..-.', 'G':'--.', 'H':'....',
                    'I':'..', 'J':'.---', 'K':'-.-',
                    'L':'.-..', 'M':'--', 'N':'-.',
                    'O':'---', 'P':'.--.', 'Q':'--.-',
                    'R':'.-.', 'S':'...', 'T':'-',
                    'U':'..-', 'V':'...-', 'W':'.--',
                    'X':'-..-', 'Y':'-.--', 'Z':'--..',
                    '1':'.----', '2':'..---', '3':'...--',
                    '4':'....-', '5':'.....', '6':'-....',
                    '7':'--...', '8':'---..', '9':'----.',
                    '0':'-----', ', ':'--..--', '.':'.-.-.-',
                    '?':'..--..', '/':'-..-.', '-':'-....-',
                    '(':'-.--.', ')':'-.--.-'}

# Getting Pydub/PyAudio to edit length of sound
m_audio = AudioSegment.from_wav("Asine.wav")
long_burst = 0.40 * 1000
short_burst = 0.20 * 1000

longSine = m_audio[:long_burst]
shortSine = m_audio[:short_burst]

# Using a dictionary to store different sound lengths
sineSounds = {
    "-":longSine,
    ".":shortSine,
}
# Function to create morse code output as string
def encrypt(message):
    cipher = ''
    for letter in message:
        if letter != ' ':
            cipher += MORSE_CODE_DICT[letter] + ' '
        else:
            cipher += ' '

    return cipher

# Function to play morse code as sound
def play_sound(message):
    for symbol in message:
         if symbol == "-":
             play(sineSounds['-'])
         if symbol == ".":
             play(sineSounds['.'])

# Main function to call both previous functions with prompts
def main():
    message = input("What word do you want to encode?: ").upper()
    print(encrypt(message))
    sound = input("Play Morse Code? ").upper()
    if sound == "y" or "yes":
        play_sound(message)

main()
```

I have double checked to make sure the cipher function is outputting a string and that the play_sound function works on its own, ie using a morse code string for the "message" argument and that sound is produced. Not to sure why when it is placed inside the Main() it doesnt produce sound.

Comment: you are only **printing** the morse code, you never store the value of encrypt() and then you pass a message as-is to play_sound() - eg the message is not converted to morse.

Comment: Additionally: `if sound == "y" or "yes":` is seen as `if (sound == "y") or ("yes"):` and this will always be true.